# Not being able to access a variable in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to get the username of the commenter to comment on an article. For this, I perform a query from the articles table (sorgu2). Finally, I found the username of the person who made the comment, but I got an error.

I'm searching for an article from the articles table and I wanted to get the username of the person who wrote this article and use it in another query.

```
mistake:UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'cevaplanan' where it is not associated with a value
```

How do I solve this?

```
@app.route('/yorum/<string:article_title>/', methods=["GET","POST"])
def yorum_ekle(article_title):

    cevap = CevapVer(request.form)
    form = ArticleForm(request.form)

    if request.method=="POST" and cevap.validate():
        icerik = cevap.icerik.data
        cursor2 = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cnt = form.content.data
        tit = form.title.data
        sorgu2 = "SELECT author FROM articles WHERE title = %s AND content = %s "
        cursor2.execute(sorgu2,(cnt,tit))
        sonuclar = cursor2.fetchall()
        cevaplanan = None

        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        sorgu = "insert into yorum(icerik,cevaplayan,cevaplanan) values(%s,%s,%s)"
        cursor.execute(sorgu,(icerik,session["username"],cevaplanan))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cursor.close()

        flash("Yorum eklendi","success")

    return render_template('cevapla.html', article_title=article_title, cevap=cevap)
```

Comment: you have set session['username'] = request.form['username'] before accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

mistake:UnboundLocalError: **cannot access local variable 'cevaplanan' where it is not associated with a value.**

Change default value of `'cevaplanan'` parameter as `empty string('')` instead of `None`. Then try again

Also, cannot see your session parameter where is defined  `session["username"]`